# Error Plugin: sfdx-cli retrieve manifest unsuccessful

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

After updating my sfdx cli to latest release, when trying to retrieve package manifest i see the below error even with a new workspace.

````
module: @oclif/config@1.17.0
task: runHook postsourceupdate
plugin: sfdx-cli
root: /Users/myname/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.75.0-5521f40d11
See more details with DEBUG=*
13:57:30.412 sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest /Users/myname/vs code workspace/folername/manifest/package.xml```
````

Comment: Retrieve fails while trying to pull all metadata to my vs code environment. Not sure how i can fix this, also i have updated all my plugins and related dependencies.

Comment: The error seems similar to https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/149 . You might want to create a new issue on https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/new/choose with elaborate details.

Comment: Thanks @Swetha I added a github issue here https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/659